# C - Finding the max value using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, max

Im new to C. Say if

```
struct test{
   int val;
   struct test *next
};
```

If a list has been created using this struct, how do you find the maximum value via pointers?

Assuming list is filled with objects of the above struct, I have tried

```
struct test *t1 = malloc(sizeof (struct test));
struct test *t2 = malloc(sizeof (struct test));
While (list !=NULL){
  int max=0;
  struct test *t1, *t2;
  if(t1->val < t2->val){
     max = t2->val;             
  }
 list = list->next;
}
```

But I guess I dont understand the logic behind it. I just need an explanation or an example on how to find the maximum value of a list of structs using pointers. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (to me) on the following points: what you are trying to do, whether or not the code does what you want it to do, if not, what the difference is between what you get and what you want, and if it does do what you want just which part of it you don't understand

Comment: @Jasper I just need an explanation or an example on how to find the maximum value of a list of structs

Comment: But to me it looks a lot like the example you provided does actually do what you want it to do. All you are doing is very basic, so unless you tell me which part about it you don't understand, I can't explain the part you don't understand.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, I see the mistake you made.

Comment: You want to know the max value within two lists ? or you just want the maximum value inside a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you out understanding (I guess)

snippet:

```
max = t1->val; /* take first value */
/* this is one way of traveling through the simple (?) list */
for(pointer = t1->next; pointer; pointer = pointer->next)
     max = pointer->val > max ? pointer->val : max;

printf("max: %d\n", max);
```

EDIT: assuming t1 refers to a populated list.

Comment: Reassigning `max` to itself is a little pointless; you should write the simpler `if (pointer->val > max) max = pointer->val;`.  There are times when using the ternary `?:` operator is appropriate; this is not one of those times.